# Color.White is getting skipped when using drawString() java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, colors, background-color

When I was trying to draw white letters on a black background I noticed something weird.

```
public WhiteOnBlackPanel() {
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255));
    g.drawString("Hello World",100,100);
    g.drawLine(0,0,100,100);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(new WhiteOnBlackPanel());
    frame.setTitle("Hello World");
    frame.setSize(600,400);
    frame.setLocation(100,100);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setVisible(true); // The frame is visible from now on
}
```

**! Don't look at the code in the images, just look at the frame !**

Gave me this:
[image: "White" letters on a black background]

Lines, however, were being drawn well.

[image: "White" letters and a white line on a black background]

When I took a different, but very close, color (254, 255, 255), I got this

[image: White letters on a black background]

Why is `java.awt.Graphics` blocking pure white (255,255,255) letters from being drawn (even when it is on a black background) ?

Tia, Charlie

Comment: Call `setVisible(true)` ***LAST***, after adding all components and setting things up. Don't override paint but rather paintComponent. Finally, never display code as an image. Your GUI, sure, but never code. How can we copy, paste and test your code now?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Edited code to your suggestions. The screenshot happened to be with Eclipse in the background. Added full code to question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels See my code, `frame.setVisible(true)` is called last. Don't mind the code in the images, the results stay the same ._.

Comment: The color resulting from 255,255,255 is the same as 0,0,0: BLACK. I don't know why this is so, and haven't found an explanation or any hint that this should be an error. Also, setColor( 0xFFFFFF ) or using 1.0F,1.0F,1.0F has the same effect. You can set alpha a little off the max (254 or 0.999) and it'll show as white, but not with full 1.0F/255 alpha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bug in jdk1.8.0_20, at least in Linux (Ubuntu): 0xFFFFFFFF appears as BLACK. Changing alpha or one of the RGB values results in "almost white".

jdk1.7.0_67 works fine on the same system.

Checked all forms of setColor.

**Later** Found that bug is reported: [JDK-8054638 : White color is not painted](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8054638)

Affected Versions: 8u11,8u25

**This bug only affects Linux; on Windows everything works fine.**

Comment: This is also the case when using "jdk1.8.0_25". Is this already reported to Oracle ?

Comment: Here is the bug report: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8054638. The bug is to be fixed in jdk1.8.0_40, which is not yet released.

Comment: Isn't it weird the line is drawn perfectly ?

Answer (score 2):

Call setVisible(true) LAST, after adding all components and setting things up. Don't override paint but rather paintComponent. For instance, this works fine:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ShowColor extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 600;
   private static final int PREF_H = 400;

   public ShowColor() {
      setBackground(Color.black);
   }

   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255));
      g.drawString("Hello World",100,100);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGUI() {
      ShowColor paintEg = new ShowColor();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("ShowColor");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(paintEg);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Executed your code, but the String from `.drawString()` is still not displayed with Color (255,255,255)

Comment: @Charlie: then I'm afraid that I'm at a loss to explain what could be wrong

Answer (score -1):

you are adding a panel to a frame. setVisible(true) to the JFrame. Without this it won't be visible.

Comment: Ehm, I did `frame.setVisible(true)`, right ? The line is being drawn correctly. Why doesn't the String though?